# Convert hierarchy in an ordered list of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, hierarchy

I tried to make a simple list that represents hierarchy of items.

```
Tags have simple structure like
   [Id]
  ,[Name]
  ,[ParentTagId]
```

I try to make the follwing result table:
`ID`, `ParentID`, `Name`, `Lev`, `LevelDynamic`, `RowNumber`
`LevelDyanmic` is for rendering. It contains a delta of level changes. The order of returned rows is important.

```
WITH cte (ParentID, ID, Name, lev, shift)
              AS(SELECT   ParentTagID,
                            ID,
                            Name,
                            1,
                            ID * 10000
                   FROM     dbo.Tag
                   where ParentTagID is null
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   e.ParentTagId,
                            e.ID,
                            e.Name,
                            lev + 1,
                            shift + lev * 100 + 1
                   FROM     cte
                            INNER JOIN dbo.Tag AS e ON e.ParentTagId = cte.ID
                 )
                  select cte.ID,
                     cte.ParentID,
                  cte.Name,
                  cte.lev,
                  cte.shift,
                  CAST(cte.lev - (LAG(cte.lev, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY cte.shift)) as int) as LevelDynamic,
                  CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cte.shift) as int) AS RowNumber
                  from CTE
                 order by shift asc
```

But that query returns me not correct results, the order of sibling elements is incorrect, it related to incorrect shift calculation. Could you help me with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need tree nodes in depth-first  order

```
with tag as (
    select * from (values
     (1,'.Net',cast(null as int)),
     (2,'EF',1),
     (3,'NHib',1),
     (4,'CF',2),
     (5,'Java',null),
     (6,'JRE',3)) t([Id],[Name],[ParentTagId])
),
cte (ParentID, ID, Name, lev, shift)AS(
  SELECT   ParentTagID,
                ID,
                Name,
                1,
                row_number() over(order by id)
       FROM     Tag
       where ParentTagID is null
       UNION ALL
       SELECT   e.ParentTagId,
                e.ID,
                e.Name,
                lev + 1,
                shift * 100 + row_number() over(order by e.id)
       FROM     cte
       INNER JOIN Tag AS e ON e.ParentTagId = cte.ID
)
select *,
   CAST(cte.lev - LAG(cte.lev, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY cast(shift as varchar(50))) as int) as LevelDynamic,
   CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cast(shift as varchar(50))) as int) AS RowNumber   
from cte
order by cast(shift as varchar(50))
```